# Check response status code with PHP / cURL (file_get_contents_curl)

Tags: php, curl

I use this function (from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8543512/14308375)) with cURL in PHP:

```
<?php
function file_get_contents_curl($url) {
    $ch = curl_init();

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER, TRUE);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, TRUE);       

    $data = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);

    return $data;
}
```

This works quite well - - for example, that way I can get the 'body' of a JSON. Like this:

```
<?php
$crossrefurl = 'https://api.crossref.org/works/10.1163/1871191X-13020004';
$obj = file_get_contents_curl($crossrefurl);

# convert to json
$obj = json_decode($obj, true);
```

What I don't know is: **how can I get the response status code** (given that my ´curl`-commands are in a function)?

Specifically, I want to find out whether the response status code is `429` in which case I would let the script sleep for 5 seconds (to avoid being rate-limited).

According to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62966214/14308375), the code should be something like:

```
<?php
if(($httpcode == 429)) { sleep(5); }
```

... but how do I get to `$httpcode` in the first place?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Could use https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.get-headers.php to get status code... or `curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE)`https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-getinfo.php

Comment: @user3783243, thank you! But where exactly should this be placed? Not really in the function, right? How would I store that information into `$httpcode`?

Comment: You could return an array, put status code as index 0 and `$data` as next index. You need CURL connection open to use this.